# Ubuntu kernel recompilation unable to enable flag : CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT

Tags: kernel, 64-bit, kvm-virtualization

I want to see ZSMALLOC internal information in Ubuntu 16.04 (in amd64 kvm-qemu). SO I tried to recompile ubuntu Kernel by adding CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT=y in .config file.

Following is what I tried:

```
$ mkdir linux.ubuntu-16.04
$ cd linux.ubuntu-16.04
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
$ make -j8
$ make install
```

However, I cannot find ZSMALLOC debug information. I cannot find a directory called zsmalloc inside `/sys/kernel/debug`

What should I do to see zsmalloc debug information?

---

```
Result of command :
```

#grep -irn CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT *

```
    [12:57:13] mac@mac-qemu:~/linux.ubuntu-16.04/linux-hwe-4.8.0 $ grep -irn CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT *
    arch/s390/configs/default_defconfig:73:CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT=y
    arch/s390/configs/gcov_defconfig:69:CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT=y
    arch/s390/configs/performance_defconfig:69:CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT=y
    arch/s390/defconfig:60:CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT=y
    debian/build/build-generic/.config:578:CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT=y
    debian/build/build-generic/.config.old:9395:CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT=y
    debian/tmp/boot/config-4.8.17:578:CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT=y
    debian/linux-image-4.8.0-54-hello-generic/boot/config-4.8.0-54-hello-generic:578:CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT=y
    debian/hdrtmp/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.17/.config:578:CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT=y
    debian/linux-headers-4.8.0-54-hello-generic/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-54-hello-generic/.config:578:CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT=y
    debian/linux-headers-4.8.0-54-hello-generic/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-54-hello-generic/.config.old:578:CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT=y
    debian.hwe/config/annotations:9494:CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT                            policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'y', 'powerpc': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
    debian.hwe/config/config.common.ubuntu:9396:CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT=y
    debian.master/config/annotations:9494:CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT                            policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'y', 'powerpc': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
    debian.master/config/config.common.ubuntu:9396:CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT=y
    debian.master/info/OVERRIDES:4:CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT=y
    Documentation/vm/zsmalloc.txt:36:With CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT, we could see zsmalloc internal information via
include/generated/autoconf.h:1142:#define CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT 1
include/config/auto.conf:1140:CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT=y
mm/zsmalloc.c:163:#ifdef CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT
mm/zsmalloc.c:262:#ifdef CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT
mm/zsmalloc.c:579:#ifdef CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT
mm/zsmalloc.c:701:#else /* CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You edit configs in a wrong file and build the kernel a wrong way.
The Ubuntu (actually Debian) way to change configs and build is following:

The config should be set in `debian.master/config/config.common.ubuntu`

It is there but commented out

```
# CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT is not set
```

Change it to

```
CONFIG_ZSMALLOC_STAT=y
```

Then run

```
fakeroot debian/rules clean
fakeroot debian/rules binary-generic binary-headers
```

to compile.

Instead of the last command you can use

```
fakeroot debian/rules DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=parallel=8  binary-headers binary-generic
```

if you want to have 8 paralell processes (analog of -j8).

Another (probably more conventional way) is to run

```
fakeroot debian/rules clean
fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs
```

Then choose the config you want to edit, then go to

"Processor type and features -> Memory allocator for compressed pages" and enable it there.

Comment: Run `fakeroot debian/rules clean` first.

Comment: I did clean first. Clean worked, but not rest of the commands.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? What happened to the next command?

Comment: $ fakeroot debian/rules binary-generic binary-headers                                                           [2]
make: *** No rule to make target 'binary-generic'.  Stop.

Comment: Hold on. I will look what happens when you get the source this way.

Comment: It works for me. Please add listings to your question, not to the comment box.

Comment: I removed my old source files and got new one. Now fakeroot commands to compile  is working. It is going to take a while to finish compilation. Let me check whether this worked. Thanks a lot!